# What's the equivalent of a GROUP BY statement within a FOREACH statement?

Tags: apache-pig

I have the following schema:

`raw3: {group: (field1: int,field2: chararray,field3: chararray),raw2: {(field1: int,field2: chararray,field4: chararray,field3: chararray,field5: boolean)}}`

What I am trying to do is extract the most frequent value of field4 and the most frequent of field field5 along with the group fields (field1, field2, field3).

I know that GROUP BY is not allowed (yet) with FOREACH statements. How can I accomplice the same functionality without writing a UDF?

**Example:**

```
input: ((1,2,3), {(1,2,a,3,x),(1,2,b,3,x),(1,2,a,3,x),(1,2,v,3,x),(1,2,f,3,z),(1,2,a,3,z)})

output: (1,2,a,3,x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten both the group tuple and the raw2 bag, and then GROUP by field1,field2,field3, field5 and get a count, and then group by field1,field2,field3 and get the value of field5 for the maximal value of count (using nested sort and limit or Piggybank's ExtremalTupleByNthField UDF).